# how to use clipboard plugin with a phonegap build app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Has anyone gotten the clipboard plugin to work with "PhoneGap Build"?
I can't get it to work.  I'm currently useing phonegap 3.1.0
My app is for android and IOS.  I've only tested the clipboard plugin on android so far, and it isn't working.

in my config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.verso.cordova.clipboard" />
```

in my javascript:

```
window.plugins.clipboard.copy('some text',function(){alert('success');},function(response){alert('error:' + response);});
window.plugins.clipboard.paste(function(text){alert('paste success:' + text);},function(response){alert('paste error:' + response);});
```

The way I have it above, the script runs, but for both the copy and paste calls, the error function is executed and the response is "Class not found".

I have tried the above call window.plugins.copy, cordova.plugins.copy 
both of those just cause the script to abort.

phonegap is loading just fine and the deviceready function has already fired before I attempt the above calls.

Under the plugins tab on the phonegap build webpage for my app:
Installed 3rd Party Plugins
com.verso.cordova.clipboard     0.1.0

Comment: You've made the plugin works? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be unrelated to the copy/paste plugin. In phonegap 3.1 you have to reference all the phonegap plugins you want to use. In this case, I'm guessing you have a function that checks if the user has an internet connection? If so, you need to add     to your config.xml